# Django-how to implement javascript for the Save button in Html to help redirect to a new url

Tags: javascript, html, django

I searched the relevant question and get answers to design the button as a form

```
<form action='/someurl/{{someobject.id}}',method='post'>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

,this answer works fine but this button cannot align with other buttons as it is a form & it doesnot allow confirmation pop up of clicking.Also I wonder whether it is really the common way to implement this.

I am writing a page with the button

`<input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="edit()"/>`

```
<script>
    function edit() {
        var c = confirm("Do you really want to edit the info?");
        if (c == true) {

        }
    }
</script>
```

How am I going to write the script so that it will have the same function as action='/someurl/' in the form brackets and help me pass the id of the object (which is to be used by the view corresponding to the'someurl/') ?

Comment: Get the URL from action attribute and refer to this [link](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html). If this is what you want

Comment: Hi thanks for recommending,but seems it cannot work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="edit({{someobject.id}})"/>

<script>
function edit(id) {
    var c = confirm("Do you really want to edit the info?");
    if (c == true) {
           window.location = '/someurl/'+id
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, but I think there is some problem in the id variable, lets say someobject.id =3 ,it will direct to the page of  /someurl/id instead of /someurl/3

Comment: Yes i understood your problem..I have edited the code try this it will work for sure..change it to window.location='/someurl/'+id

Answer (score 0):

Being a submit button makes no difference in the js confirmation dialog.The below code works for me.

```
<form action=/url method=post id=f>
...
<input type=submit value='blah'>
</form>

<script>
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm('Sure?'))
        {
            $('#f').submit();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    });
</script>
```

And as for alignment,try using a `table` for aligning your buttons horizontally or vertically.